# While printing, existing styling should not apply

Tags: css, media-queries, less

I have an HTML table that is having the class which defines some styling properties

```
    .table-bordered {
        -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
        -moz-border-left-colors: none;
        -moz-border-right-colors: none;
        -moz-border-top-colors: none;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-color: #DDDDDD #DDDDDD #DDDDDD -moz-use-text-color;
        border-image: none;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        border-style: solid solid solid none;
        border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
    }
```

while printing this table this styling should not apply. instead only the following styling should apply. now its mixing the both.

```
      @media print {
        table#addressbook {
            border: solid #000 !important;
            border-width: 1px 0 0 1px !important;
        }
        table#addressbook th,table#addressbook td {
            border: solid #000 !important;
            border-width: 0 1px 1px 0 !important;
        }
    }
```

I am using Less.js to create CSS . how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude some styles from printing (e.g. `.table-bordered`), consider moving it to `@media screen`.